# Error al colocar formulario de Mailchimp

Tags: html, css, blogger

Cuando intento colocar este formulario en el layout de mi blog en blogger me aparecen estos errores:

> 1. Error parsing XML, line 3958, column 240: Attribute name "novalidate" associated with an element type "form" must be followed by the ' = ' character
> 2. Error parsing XML, line 3961, column 109: Attribute name "required" associated with an element type "input" must be followed by the ' = ' character.

Si lo coloco en otro lado que no sea el layout lo acepta.

El código es el siguente:

```html
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/horizontal-slim-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
 #mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; width:100%;}
 /* Add your own MailChimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
    We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
</style>
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="//exortechnologies.us16.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=a86e4e21e1cb9eae9c50f81eb&amp;id=548054fc89" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
 <label for="mce-EMAIL">Suscríbete y recibe primero que nadie nuestras publicaciones ¡Es GRATIS!</label>
 <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_a86e4e21e1cb9eae9c50f81eb_548054fc89" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>

<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Los atributos que agregas al form y al input deben tener valores, el escribir el atributo o no escribirlo, no es lo que hace que este se active tienes que darle valor true o false segun lo que quieras, de no poner el atributo novalidate y required , se tomarian sus valores por defecto. Para establecerlo tu tienes que poner 
 o  "false" segun lo que quieras establecer

el error mismo te lo indica tienes que darle valor a esos atributos al igual que haces con los demas, si no, no escribas esos atributos y tomaran su valor por defecto

Comment: Espero haberte ayudado

Comment: Gracias, es que ese código lo da el mismo Mailchimp. Cuando quito los atributos me deja correr el código pero no se ve. Tal vez es algo incompatible con Blogger.

Comment: no hace falta que quites los atributos si no quieres, pero tienes que darle un valor ej: novalidate ="true" o novalidate="false"